# Active directory authenticatoin when connecting to Azure SQL database

Tags: authentication, go, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

Need to access an Azure SQL database but because of how it was created I need to use Active Directory-Integrated authentication.

I don't see any samples for go that would be helpful.  If I could use a connection string I know how to do this, but with the GO driver it doesn't seem obvious

Any and all ideas are appreciated

Comment: The Go standard library contains no `database/sql` driver to work with DBMSes produced by Microsoft®, so what exactly 3rd-party package are you using as the driver? Is it [github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb)?

Comment: If the answer to my question is "yes", then please read the project's README file and use an Internet search engine to search for examples. I'd start from reading [these issues](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+in%3Atitle+azure).

Comment: The answer is yes, based on Microsoft's post about using GO with SQL.  As for use an Internet search engine -- well, i appreciate sarcasm as much as the next guy but let's just say my search for the specific authentication i need because of pre-reqs set-up by others turned up not much that was useful.  Could have missed it, so thought I would ask folks who might have seen this.  I get this might not work and I might have to use another language.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good article on the subject that can be found at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#using-an-azure-ad-identity-to-connect-from-a-client-application).

You do have a few options, with various pros and cons. However, the simplest is to inject the AAD username/password into the connection string by setting the property `Authentication` to `Active Directory Password` and then providing the properties `UID` and `PWD`.